# Clarification regarding bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Can anyone explain the part where `read i` is used. Where did the `i` come from.

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.sample gaara@stuid.student.com:ready/$2/*.zip ./$2 > slate.out 2>&1

ls -1 $2/* > curr.lst 2>/dev/null

while
read i
do
  if
    test -e ../done/"$i"
  then
      diff "$i" ../done/"$i" >/dev/null 2>&1
    if
      test $? -eq 0
    then
      rm "$i"
    fi
  fi
done < curr.lst
```

Comment: The short answer to this is **No.** There is plenty of documentation available for Bash, scp, diff, and all of the other parts of this script. If you have a *specific* question about part of the syntax, revise your question to say so.

Comment: I get that this is sort of demanding, but I'm badly stuck. And the part where `read i` is used I'm nit getting where did the `i` come from.

Comment: read command is reading the data from file descriptor you specified at the end...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax for `read` is commonly used to process multiple lines from a file. Let's simplify things by omitting the inner loop:

```
while
read i
do
  # Process i
done < curr.lst
```

The 'while x do; done' syntax is pretty basic and easily understood, but the addition of the I/O redirect can be confusing. When you add the `< curr.lst` after `done`, it means "use the contents of this file as `stdin` for the conditional. So, if you now omit the loop, you get:

```
read i < curr.lst
```

It is now clear that `read` is getting its input from `curr.lst` and setting the variable `i` to the contents of each line. So, what that block of code basically means is "process each line of `curr.lst` as the variable `i` with the code inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

"read" , according to man page (type `man page` in a shell), read from a file descriptor.

In your code, the loop is made for each row from "curr.lst", which are put in the variable `$i`

Comment: So in the last line `done < curr.lst` .Is that the line from which the curr.lst is placed in $i and if I place some other file will the loop be created for the new file.

Comment: @Dark Matter - Here's a helpful article on some of the essentials of reading to and from files, including the `read line < file.txt` idiom: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-one/

Comment: nice article from @Darragh ! Also some other explanations : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: `man page` will not provide any useful information on `read`. In most cases, neither will `man read`, except to inform the user that it is a Bash builtin. The better documentation for `read` can be found in the [Bash Beginners Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) and the [Advanced Bash Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).